# Is it still true that CS PhD programs don't do interviews?

Tags: graduate-admissions, interview

I'm currently an applicant and have tried to read extensively regarding this topic. It seems to be the consensus that "interviews are rare for CS PhD programs." However, observations from places like Grad Cafe (not the best source, but there's not really an alternative), anecdotes from other professors and students, etc. all indicate that in reality professors interview applicants extensively. After all, this makes sense since you're basically an employer in charge of someone for at least a few years.

I've also read that in many cases interviews happen mostly for international applicants to assess their ability to communicate in English. However, I've noticed a vast number of domestic applicants (in the US) and international applicants with high TOEFL scores also receiving interviews.

My question is, is it still the case that interviews are rare for CS PhD programs?

I'm also curious where the consensus that CS PhD programs don't do interviews stemmed from, because come to think of it I haven't heard of any professor who would be comfortable with agreeing to advise someone just by looking at their application.

Comment: _I haven't heard of any professor who would be comfortable with agreeing to advise someone just by looking at their application_ — Neither have I.  But PhD students (at least in CS in the US) do not have permanent advisors when they are admitted.